# Manage multiple variable in one, big if-else

Tags: if-statement

I have to solve problem with some Word's like editor and it's codes, witch return some logic.
Now I have over 4000 variables:

```
string code1 = "onePlusOne";
string code2 = "onePlusTwo";
...
string code4000 = "onePlusFourThousands"
```

and the same number of logic if-else statements:

```
if(code == code1)
    return 2;
else if(code == code2)
    return 3;
...
else if(code = code4000)
    return 4001;
```

Client can paste code into editor to get value, for example:

"Some test, #onePlusTwenty# some test."

..and the result will be:

"Some test, 21 some test."

My problems are:

- over 4000 variables in code,
- over 4000 lines of if-else (with returns    it's over 10 000 lines).
- contradiction with SOLID :)

I was thinking about store those codes in database (but this solve almost nothing), also I can sort those codes into groups (but this only will help me to split if-else into many others if-else).

I will be grateful for any idea how to mange this.

Comment: Object?? Or a `key-value` Structure??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `key-value` structure for storing your data and instead of writing +10,000 LOC, use a `for` loop to replace your values. For exampleL

```
struct key_value {
   string key;
   int value;
};
```

And `for` loop will be like

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAPSIZE; i ++) {
     if(YOUR_COMPARE_MODULE) {
         // replace here
     }
}
```